# ASP.Net Mvc Ajax.BeginForm with a submit button fires two times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

When using `Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions(...))` with a submit button. It calls the action method two times. What could be the reason? When I replace `Ajax.BeginForm` with `Html.BeginForm` it works fine as expected.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onTemplateSaveSuccess(data);", OnComplete = "hideProgress();" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" name="templatePageNumber" id="templatePageNumber" />
        <input type="hidden" name="templatePageSize" id="templatePageSize" />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TemplateCode)

        <div class="event-subheading">Templates </div>
        <div id="TemplateInputDiv">

            <fieldset>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Template Name </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TemplateName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TemplateName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Type</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="TemplateType" class="radio-cover" value="1" checked="checked" /><span class="radio-txt">Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> <input type="radio" name="TemplateType" class="radio-cover" value="2" /> <span class="radio-txt">SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> <input type="radio" name="TemplateType" class="radio-cover" value="3" /><span class="radio-txt">Badge</span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label>Content </label>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TemplateContent, 10, 40, null)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TemplateContent)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label></label><a href="myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><label class="hint--success" style="color:#23527c;font-weight:bold;" data-hint="Use hand button in the Dynamic Data window to insert the dynamic data tag to the current position of the editor."><b>Dynamic Data</b></label></a>
                        <span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label></label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submitTemplate" name="submitTemplate" class="sub_mit" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="sub_mit" id="cancel" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

    }
```

Comment: Nothing you have shown us would cause that. What is `onTemplateSaveSuccess(data)`?

Comment: may be jquer-unobtrusive-ajax is included twice. that casues this issue

Comment: check onTemplateSaveSuccess(data); method, maybe it is firing ajax reuqest again.

Comment: Jquery was included twice as Ehsan Sajjad said. 

Ehsan, give it as a formal answer, so that I can tick on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check **onTemplateSaveSuccess(data);** method, maybe it is firing ajax reuqest again.

2. Goto netwrok tab in the chrome (F12) and inspect the ruqest made by the client. It will tell you exactly why second request is made and who is making it

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code for onTemplateSaveSuccess method. Try return false from this method and set e.preventDefault() at the end of this method. If that doesn't work then try writting e.stopPropagation() too